# Calculating the power of a lightbulb

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, power

How do I calculate the [power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_%28physics%29) of a lightbulb? I have values but I don't know the equation to use.

Comment: What values do you have?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I used Ohm's law to solve. sorry I've never taken a physics class before and am trying to teach myself for fun. the values i had were .480A at 120V. I calculated 57.6 J as my answer

Comment: This is not a conceptual question.

Comment: The resistance of a light bulb is not linier, it changes with temperature. Cold resistance will give different results from those measured when lit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Volt and a Ammeter to calculate , P=VI , shouldn't that be simple enough

Comment: what do the p, v and I stand for?

Comment: P = Power
V = Voltage/Potential Difference
I = Current

Answer (score -3):

P=VI

480A at 120V. I calculated 57.6 J

Comment: Correct equation, but I guess you mean $480mA=0.48A$... Also Joule J is a unit of energy, not Power. Volts times Amps is Watts=Joule/second.